# google maps api V3 (geolocation)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am able to run the google maps api to get the geo locations only on the firefox browser. It does not find the geo location on safari and Google crome. It fails stating geolocation service failed. Can some one tell me how I could make this geollocation example run on safari and google crome. I have got this example from google maps api V3

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="http://code.google.com//apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
        });

        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
      var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
      var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
      content: content
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chrome has an icon in the URL address bar, on the right, next to the star icon used to bookmark a site.  The geolocation icon looks like a target.  Don't know about Safari...

Comment: Which reason is it failing - geolocation service failed, or browser doesn't support it?

Answer (score 0):

> > Can some one tell me how I could make this geollocation example run on safari and google crome.

without knowing the versions, perhaps informing the browser to interpret the markup as html5 with

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

     <html>

     <head>

     ....
```